# ¿Como llenar un DropdownList de acuerdo al valor de un input? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un formulario en un proyecto ASP.NET MVC, en el cual al escribir un código en un input y al momento de escribirlo debera buscar ese codigo en una tabla de base de datos y llenar un dropdownlist, pero el dropdownlist no se llena
Aquí mi código:

```html
 //Lista de campos
public JsonResult GetCamposList(string Codigo)
{
bd.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
List<TblCampos> ListCampos = bd.TblCampos.Where(x => x.Codigo == Codigo).ToList();
return Json(ListCampos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#Codigo").change(function () {
 $.get("Solicitud/GetCamposList", { Codigo: $("#Codigo").val() }, function (data) {
 $("#Codigo").empty();
 $.each(data, function (index, row) {
 $("#Codigo").append("<option value='" + row.Cod_Campo + "'>'"+row.Descripcion+"'</option>")
 });
 });
 });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<div class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary subtitulo">Codigo:</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Codigo" name="Codigo" maxlength="5" minlength="5" required="">           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary subtitulo">Campo:</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cod_Campo, new SelectList(" "), "--Seleccione un campo--",new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
</div>
```

Modelo

```html
 public partial class ProdMuestreo
 {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Codigo { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> Cod_Campo { get; set; }
 public string Ubicacion { get; set; }
 public string Telefono { get; set; }
 public List<TblCampos> Campos { get; set; }
 }

//ListCampos
public partial class TblCampos
{
public short Cod_Empresa { get; set; }
public string Codigo { get; set; }
public short Cod_Campo { get; set; }
public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

Ejemplo de datos

```html
Tabla ProdMuestreo 
 Id 0
 Codigo 00050
 Cod_Campo 1
 Ubicacion Mexico
 Telefono 55555555

Tabla Campos
Cod_Empresa 1
Codigo 00050
Cod_Campo 1
Descripcion Los Girasoles
```

Comment: Pues son varios pasos, primero crea otra accion que te devuelva una lista de items de tipo valor -texto. Del lado del usuario, agrega un llamado ajax para llamar a la accion  en la con los valres de respuesta se llena el dropdownlist, por ultimo agrega un metodo con javascript para cuando se cambie el valor del input este llame a la funcion ajax.

Comment: @MiguelZarate ¿no tienes algun tutorial paso a paso? porque no tengo ni idea, Gracias

Comment: en este articulo tienes la respuesta,la ventaja es que viene el codigo fuente , https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar un ejemplo del JSON y de parte de los datos que tienes?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx, ¿a que se refiere con de parte de los datos que tienes?

Comment: ese "de" se me fue xD!,  coloca una parte de los datos que tengas en la BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que intentas hacer el append en el mismo input, para corregir este problema primero asigna un Id a tu dropdownlist, y posteriormente hazle el append, no estabas tan lejos de la solución, tu código quedaría así:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary subtitulo">Codigo:</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Codigo" name="Codigo" maxlength="5" minlength="5" required="">           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary subtitulo">Campo:</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cod_Campo, new SelectList(" "), "--Seleccione un campo--",new { @id = "IdCodCampo",@class="form-control"})
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Codigo").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Solicitud/GetCamposList?Codigo=" + $("#Codigo").val(), function (result) {

            var select = $("#IdCodCampo");
            select.empty();


            $.each(result, function (index, itemData) {
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: itemData.Cod_Campo,
                    text: itemData.Descripcion
                }));
            });


        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Disculpa me manda este error data is not defined

Comment: Si, ya revisé el código había un error, no era "data" el nombre de la variable que regresaba el ajax si no "result". Vuelve a intentarlo, lo acabo de modificar.